# Responsive DIV Row + Column Layout With Absolute Div Overlay

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to achieve the attached layout [for screenshot click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhYdw.png)

And have it responsive so that  DIV B drops below DIV A on resize screen

I have absolutely positioned DIV B so that it covers content and DIV C

DIV C has to be full width and so does DIV A

Any help would be appreciated I can achieve the layout with just desktop but not responsive

Comment: what you have code so far? please paste it along with fiddle

Comment: where is the code that you have tried? Post it here

Comment: Please post you code

Answer (score 1):

you can see it woking here https://jsfiddle.net/DeeptiC/83ox7yLf/4/

change the screen size to see it the responsiveness

```css
.div-a {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  background: green;
}
.div-bwrapper {
  max-width: 1170px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.div-b {
  width: 200px;
  height: 350px;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: -60px;
  right: 0px;
}
.div-c {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  background: Yellow;
}
.inner-wrap {
  max-width: 1170px;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .div-bwrapper {
    width: 100%
  }
  .div-b {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="div-a">
  <div class="inner-wrap">
    DIV A
  </div>
</div>
<div class="div-bwrapper">
  <div class="div-b">
    <div class="inner-wrap">
      DIV B
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="div-c">
  <div class="inner-wrap">
    DIV c
  </div>
</div>
```